# Configure Valgrind to return non-zero exit status if invalid reads detected

Tags: valgrind

Is it possible to configure Valgrind to return a non-zero exit status if invalid reads are detected but no actual memory leaks?

(I want to use Valgrind as part of some automated tests for student C code submissions.)

Comment: Have you thought about passing the output of valgrind through eg. a bash script checking the parts you are interested about and returning own error codes?

Comment: Seen `--error-exitcode` at https://linux.die.net/man/1/valgrind?

Comment: Yes.  valgrind |& grep "Invalid" will tell me what I want to know.  I was just curious if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: --error-exitcode is working now.  I swear it wasn't when I tried it initially.  (A more detailed answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246470/how-to-get-in-script-whether-valgrind-found-memory-leaks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option --error-for-leak-kinds=none :

```
--errors-for-leak-kinds=kind1,kind2,..  which leak kinds are errors?
                                              [definite,possible]
   where kind is one of:
     definite indirect possible reachable all none
```